# Setting opacity to svg path elements based on the keyframe animation state

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm trying to set an opacity of 1 to the lines that I have in a gauge component, here's a link to the code: https://codepen.io/SergiuT/pen/RwgmOqw

Here's the code:

```
    <svg width="244" height="126" viewBox="0 0 244 126" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <mask id="mask0" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="4" y="0" width="236" height="122">
            <rect x="4.97656" width="234.175" height="122" fill="url(#paint0_linear)" />
        </mask>
        <g mask="url(#mask0)">
            <circle cx="122" cy="125.5" r="115" fill="url(#paint1_radial)" />
        </g>
    
        <path id="line1" opacity="0.5" d="M22.5763 57.2082C10.2411 75.2339 2.76131 96.7911 2 120.032" stroke="#75FCC6" stroke-width="4"
            stroke-linecap="round" />
        <path id="line2" opacity="0.5" d="M81.134 11.9933C59.6579 19.7007 41.0318 33.3096 27.248 50.8443" stroke="#75FCC6"
            stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" />
        <path id="line3" opacity="0.5" d="M88.6836 9.56243C99.262 6.53918 110.44 4.91934 122 4.91934C133.56 4.91934 144.738 6.53919 155.317 9.56245"
            stroke="#979797" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" />
        <path id="line4" opacity="0.5" d="M162.867 11.9933C184.343 19.7007 202.969 33.3096 216.753 50.8443" stroke="#FBE850"
            stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" />
        <path id="line5" opacity="0.5" d="M221.424 57.2082C233.759 75.2339 241.239 96.791 242 120.032" stroke="#FBE850" stroke-width="4"
            stroke-linecap="round" />
    
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="122.064" y1="58.5794" x2="122.064" y2="122"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop />
                <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0" />
            </linearGradient>
            <radialGradient id="paint1_radial" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                gradientTransform="translate(122 125.5) rotate(90) scale(115)">
                <stop offset="0.765625" stop-color="#75FCC6" stop-opacity="0" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#75FCC6" stop-opacity="0.33" />
            </radialGradient>
        </defs>
    </svg>
  <div class="indicator">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.indicator {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  margin: 0 10px;

  @keyframes go {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(150deg);
    }
  }

  .wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1%;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards !important    ;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    animation: go 2s ease-in;

    .line {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 85px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      border: 1px solid white;
      height: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: The lines shine based on the value of the rotate() from .wrapper

Example: I can pass in 150deg to rotate, or 30deg, or 80deg. So I'm not going to pass all the lines everytime

Answer (score 0):

Put an `id="svg"` to your svg. Then find the animations `shine` 1 to 5.

```css
body {
    background: black   
}
.indicator {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
  @keyframes go {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(150deg);
    }
  }

  .wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1%;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards !important    ;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    animation: go 2s ease-in;
  }
  .wrapper  .line {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 85px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      border: 1px solid white;
      height: 0;
    }

#svg #line1{
    animation: shine1 2s ease-in;
}
@keyframes shine1 {
    0% {
      opacity: 1
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 0.5
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 0.5
    }
    80% {
    opacity: 0.5
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 0.5
    }
  }

#svg #line2{
    animation: shine2 2s ease-in;
}
@keyframes shine2 {
    0% {
      opacity: 0.5
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 0.5
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    80% {
    opacity: 0.5
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 0.5
    }
  }
  
#svg #line3{
    animation: shine3 2s ease-in;
}
@keyframes shine3 {
    0% {
      opacity: 0.5
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 0.5
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 0.5
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    80% {
    opacity: 1
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 0.5
    }
  }
#svg #line4{
    animation: shine4 2s ease-in;
}
@keyframes shine4 {
    0% {
      opacity: 0.5
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 0.5
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 0.5
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 0.5
    }
    80% {
    opacity: 1
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  
#svg #line5{
    animation: shine5 2s ease-in;
}
@keyframes shine5 {
    0% {
      opacity: 0.5
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 0.5
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 0.5
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 0.5
    }
    80% {
    opacity: 0.5
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="244" height="126" viewBox="0 0 244 126" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <mask id="mask0" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="4" y="0" width="236" height="122">
            <rect x="4.97656" width="234.175" height="122" fill="url(#paint0_linear)" />
        </mask>
        <g mask="url(#mask0)">
            <circle cx="122" cy="125.5" r="115" fill="url(#paint1_radial)" />
        </g>
    
        <path id="line1" opacity="0.5" d="M22.5763 57.2082C10.2411 75.2339 2.76131 96.7911 2 120.032" stroke="#75FCC6" stroke-width="4"
            stroke-linecap="round" />
        <path id="line2" opacity="0.5" d="M81.134 11.9933C59.6579 19.7007 41.0318 33.3096 27.248 50.8443" stroke="#75FCC6"
            stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" />
        <path id="line3" opacity="0.5" d="M88.6836 9.56243C99.262 6.53918 110.44 4.91934 122 4.91934C133.56 4.91934 144.738 6.53919 155.317 9.56245"
            stroke="#979797" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" />
        <path id="line4" opacity="0.5" d="M162.867 11.9933C184.343 19.7007 202.969 33.3096 216.753 50.8443" stroke="#FBE850"
            stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" />
        <path id="line5" opacity="0.5" d="M221.424 57.2082C233.759 75.2339 241.239 96.791 242 120.032" stroke="#FBE850" stroke-width="4"
            stroke-linecap="round" />
    
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="122.064" y1="58.5794" x2="122.064" y2="122"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop />
                <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0" />
            </linearGradient>
            <radialGradient id="paint1_radial" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                gradientTransform="translate(122 125.5) rotate(90) scale(115)">
                <stop offset="0.765625" stop-color="#75FCC6" stop-opacity="0" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#75FCC6" stop-opacity="0.33" />
            </radialGradient>
        </defs>
    </svg>
  <div class="indicator">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It has to be constricted by the value of the transform from .wrapper ( it's a prop I pass in dynamicly ). For example it can go to 150deg/30deg/60deg/etc